# Trouble upgrading ember-cli from 0.0.40 to 0.1.2 - transpiler doesn't like emblem anymore

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I've just [upgraded an ember-cli app from 0.0.40 to 0.1.2](https://github.com/oliverbarnes/participate-frontend/pull/79).

After following this [upgrade guide](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.2) and upgrading all the plugins as best as I could, the transpiler seems to barf on emblem files:

`➜  participate-frontend git:(upgrade-cli) ✗ ember build
version: 0.1.2
Build failed.
File: participate-frontend/templates/alert.js
Line 1: Unexpected identifier
Error: Line 1: Unexpected identifier
    at throwError (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:2579:21)
    at throwUnexpected (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:2623:13)
    at expect (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:2650:13)
    at parseArrayInitialiser (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:2783:21)
    at parsePrimaryExpression (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:3076:20)
    at /Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:5661:38
    at trackLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:5563:61)
    at parsePostfixExpression (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:3214:20)
    at /Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:5661:38
    at parseUnaryExpression (/Users/work/Projects/participate-frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/node_modules/es6-module-transpiler/dist/es6-module-transpiler.js:3278:16)`

Any ideas on what could be causing this, or on how to debug this?

Comment: Do you have the ember cli emblem plugin installed?

Comment: yes, both broccoli-emblem-compiler and ember-cli-emblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the error myself and it looks to be due to an update to the ember-template-compiler module as part of the broccoli-emblem-compiler. Per this discussion https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2357

I'm new to node module management but I did the following to peg broccoli-emblem-compiler's dependency to an older version of ember-template-compiler.

1. Add the following devDependency: "ember-template-compiler": "1.7.0-beta.1"
2. rm -rf node_modules/broccoli-emblem-compiler/
3. npm install

A bit heavy handed but it was the only way to force broccoli-emblem-compiler to use the older version of ember-template-compiler on my machine.

Comment: thanks, getting another error now, but related to ember-cli-bourbon. Progress :)